# BigQuery - which project gets the cost: dataset or query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

**If I run a query from project A on a dataset in project B does my cost go against project A or project B or some combination of both?**

It's a simple question that I have found surprisingly difficult to find an answer to. I've checked the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries) and googled, searched stack overflow to no avail. Docs read as though it would be the project that the query is run from but can't see an explicit mention.

---

UPDATE: Just to clarify, I understand there is also an ongoing storage cost for storing the data in project B but, for this question, I am specifically referring to the cost of the *query* itself

Comment: It's the project the query is run from. This caught me out as with the updated UI it's easier to see datasets across projects without explicitly changing the project at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen thru code:

```
bq = bigquery.Client(
  project_id='project_a')
bq.query_job = client.query(
  'SELECT * FROM `project_b.dataset.table`')
```

- `project_b` pays for storage
- `project_a` pays for the query

The beauty of this model is that you can make your dataset public - and you won't pay for any of the third party queries. They pay for their queries, and everyone gets a monthly free tier for querying.